# Add CSS via javascript to an element works in console but not in html structure

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to add css (margin-top) to an element on woocommerce checkout page that contains the card error messages.

This is the code:

```
const cardError = document.getElementsByClassName('sumo-pp-stripe-card-errors');
cardError[0].style.marginTop = '100px';
console.log(cardError[0]);
```

It works fine when I look at it in the console tab.
[image]

But in the real html structure I can not see any changes.
[image]

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

To add to html

```
<div id="myDIV">
This is a DIV element.
</div>
```

First make a css class
you can change your desire css style inside here

```
.mystyle {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 25px;
  background-color: coral;
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

then write js like this

```
 var element = document.getElementById("myDIV");
   element.classList.add("mystyle");
```

Comment: @hungeo please provide your html also, 
Its should work in both html & console. Maybe your implementation is wrong

Answer (score 0):

```js
const cardError = document.querySelector('.sumo-pp-stripe-card-errors');
cardError.style.marginTop = '100px';
```

```html
<div class="sumo-pp-stripe-card-errors">
  some test div
</div>
```

Well this works Check!

Comment: Thanks, but it gives me the same result as I mentioned in my question.

Comment: try  !important  like cardError.style.marginTop = '100px!important'

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that your JavaScript runs after the DOM contains the elements.

If you are adding the JavaScript code to the page itself, insert your `<script>` element at the end of the `<body>` element.

If you are adding your code to an existing script that is at the start of the document, put your code in a function, then call that function when the DOM has loaded. Like this: `document.addEventListener("load", myFunction)`